# How can I replace int values with string values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a csv file with a lot of categorical variables. 
The data originally is derived from spss and doing a further cluster analysis
on the data, I need instead of numbers the names of the variables.
So I will replace the int values by the string such as in the following example 
1 does stands for male, while 2 stands for female for example

```
df[(df['gender']==1)]['gender'] = 'male'
```

However I know it can't work, since the column contains originally int values, so replacing by string value is not possible, so first I tried to convert the column to string such as with the following code before replacing the 1 by male

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].astype(str)
```

or

```
df['gender'].apply(str)
```

However when I run the following code afterwards

```
df[(df['gender']=='1')]['gender'] = 'male'
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

So I have no clue how to handle this problem :(

Comment: @jezrael Most are int64, while some are float64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think best here is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dictionary` by all possible values in `gender`, else get `NaN`s for not matched values:

```
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map({1:'male', 2:'female'})
```

---

Problem should be mixed types in column after replacing - replaced `1` to strings `male` and original numeric `2`.

Comment: thank you very much! It did work! I have looked a while for this answer and finally it works.

Comment: @Joy - You are welcome!